# What happens if you are being tracked using an AirTag but you don't own an apple device?

Tags: find-my, airtag

While Apple positions AirTags as a tool to find things you lost, it can also be used to (most probably illegally) track other people. Assuming I don't own an iPhone/iPad, how can I figure out that this is the case and what can I do in such cases?

Comment: I understand you might want to get some advice, but this is highly opinionated as worded currently  and of [the form “what if _____ happened?”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 3):

It makes a sound.

> An AirTag that isn’t with the person who registered it for an extended period of time will also **play a sound when moved so you can find it, even if you don’t use an iOS device**.

[What to do if you find an AirTag or get an alert that an AirTag is with you - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT212227), emphasis mine

> after an AirTag has been away from its paired device for a certain amount of time, the item will automatically emit a sound notifying those around it of its presence.

An Apple executive, quoted by 9to5Mac in [Apple execs explain how AirTag is ‘stalker-proof’ and whether you should use it to track pets](https://9to5mac.com/2021/04/22/apple-execs-explain-how-airtag-is-stalker-proof-and-whether-you-should-use-it-to-track-pets/)

Comment: And when it squaks, I find it and it gets introduced to a sledgehammer.

Answer (score 0):

While AirTags are supposed to beep when moving and separated from their owner, this can be disabled by [removing the speaker](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/419945/151404).

As of December 13th, 2021, Android users can now manually scan for unexpected AirTags. [CNET](https://www.cnet.com/tech/mobile/apple-launches-airtags-and-find-my-detector-app-for-android-in-effort-to-boost-privacy/):

> Apple has released a new Android app called Tracker Detect, designed to help people who don't own iPhones or iPads to identify unexpected AirTags and other Find My network-equipped sensors that may be nearby.