# How can I deactivate the speaker on the Airtags?

Tags: airtag

I've purchased some Airtags and would like to use them as a tracker for my cat, in case it runs away. I know that Airtags start beeping after a few days if you're not around and given that they're quite loud I want to make sure that my cat doesn't get stressed out by incessant beeping around their neck.

Is there a way to completely disable the Airtags speaker via software or hardware modification? I'm okay with methods that remove warranty from the device given that the tags are quite cheap.

P.S. I am aware that Apple [doesn't "officially" recommend](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/04/22/airtags-for-items-not-pets-children/) using Airtags for tracking pets but it would still be useful for my particular usecase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it often happens, I was able to find out a [good enough video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgGNShP9H8A) on Youtube shortly after posting this question. In case the video gets deleted, here are the steps:

1. Open the battery cover
2. Carefully use a sharp tool (such as a box cutter) to lift over the edge of the internal plastic cover, then pop it open with a screwdriver
3. Remove the speaker magnet (pictured below) using a screwdriver
4. Put a bit of glue over the corners on top of the electronics board
5. Reattach the plastic cover and battery cover

[image]

Comment: And, voilla, a cheap stalking device!

Comment: @NateLockwood hopefully the cat won't mind :)